# Toggle Add to Favorite / Remove from Favorite - Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

Hi have a heart image which should add to favorite when clicked, then remove from favorite when clicked again. Both Add/Remove are working when page refreshes, but if once added and then try to remove again, and then add again is not working.

Following is the html/php

```
<a href="#"><img class="<?php if($favorite == 1){ echo 'alreadyfavorite';} else { echo 'addtofavorite';} ?>" pid="<?php echo $propertyid; ?>" fpid="<?php while($data5=$select5->fetch()){echo $data5['favorite_properties_id'];} ?>" src="../images/system/addtofavorite.png"></a>
```

This is the jquery

```
$('.addtofavorite').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ins_id = $(this).attr('pid');
    var reference = this;

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../controllers/favoritesaddremove.php',
        data: 

        {
            ins_id: ins_id
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
        $(reference).removeClass('addtofavorite').addClass('alreadyfavorite');  
        }
    });
});


$('.alreadyfavorite').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var del_id = $(this).attr('fpid');
    var reference = this;

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../controllers/favoritesaddremove.php',
        data: 

        {
            del_id: del_id
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
        $(reference).removeClass('alreadyfavorite').addClass('addtofavorite');  
        }
    });
});
```

Also can someone tell me how to wrap the code while posting on stackoverflow, seems like my html/php code is showing a horizontal scroll...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with jquery toggle class.

```
$(element).toggleClass("c1 c2");
```

also can use same classes as selectors.

```
$(".c1, .c2").toggleClass("c1 c2");
```

Comment: Class is getting toggled... and jquery effect is happening in css, but if i try another click function to work on the newly updated class.. .then the newly updated class is not getting picked up by jquery

Comment: ok got your problem.
instead of 
`$(".c1, .c2").toggleClass("c1 c2");`
...
write 
`$(element).toggleClass("c1 c2");`

as classnames are changing dynamically. and toggleclass is binding on page load. so after toggle complete class selectors will not work. use another selectors like id or data attributes.