# Jquery Toggle Class Value Not Getting Picked by Next Jquery Function

Tags: jquery, css

I have two functions add to favorite, remove from favorite which should work alternatively on clicks... but even though one functions changes the class (and gives the desired effect), the jquery is unable to pick the value of the changed class to run the other function...

html

```
<a href="#"><img class="<?php if($favorite == 1){ echo 'alreadyfavorite';} else { echo 'addtofavorite';} ?>" src="../images/system/addtofavorite.png"></a>
```

Jquery

```
// On Search Property Results Page - Add to Favorite Button (Heart)

        $('.addtofavorite').click(function() {
            alert("add");
            var reference = this;
            $(reference).toggleClass("addtofavorite alreadyfavorite");

        });


        // On Search Property Results Page - Remove from Favorite Button (Heart)
        $('.alreadyfavorite').click(function() {
            alert("delete");
            var reference = this;
            $(reference).toggleClass("addtofavorite alreadyfavorite");

    });
```

alert should say add, then css should change then alert should say delete, then css should change, then alert should say yes css should change...

only css is changing but the alert remains the same...

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle Add to Favorite / Remove from Favorite - Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934791/toggle-add-to-favorite-remove-from-favorite-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `$('.addtofavorite').click(function() {` to `$(document).on('click', '.addtofavorite', function() {` it seams to work as you would like it to.

**Note:** the css is just for visibility of the example.

Hope it helps

```js
$(document).on('click', '.addtofavorite', function() {
  alert("add");
  var reference = this;
  $(reference).toggleClass("alreadyfavorite addtofavorite");

});


// On Search Property Results Page - Remove from Favorite Button (Heart)
$(document).on('click', '.alreadyfavorite', function() {
  alert("delete");
  var reference = this;
  $(reference).toggleClass("alreadyfavorite addtofavorite");

});
```

```css
.alreadyfavorite {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow
}
.addtofavorite {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  <img class="alreadyfavorite" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding "click" to an unexciting element since you have only one of them at a time.

bind it to the parent instead

```
        $('body').on("click",".addtofavorite", function() {
            console.log("add");
            var reference = this;
            $(reference).toggleClass("addtofavorite alreadyfavorite");
        });


       $('body').on("click",".alreadyfavorite", function() {
            console.log("delete");
            var reference = this;
            $(reference).toggleClass("addtofavorite alreadyfavorite");

    });
```

http://codepen.io/Maher-Fa/pen/KaQwZX?editors=1010